# Old records appear in the Hadoop table after drop and creating new table with the same old name

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive

I have a question regarding creating tables in Hadoop.
I create external table the following way:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL HADOOP TABLE SCHEMA.TABLENAME (
  ID BIGINT NOT NULL,
  CODE INTEGER,
  "VALUE" DOUBLE
STORED AS ORC
TBLPROPERTIES ('bigsql.table.io.doAs'='false',
  'bucketing_version'='2',
  'orc.compress'='ZLIB',
  'orc.create.index'='true')
```

After I created this table I run Jenkins job (with sqoop process) which loads 70.000.000 records to this table.
Then I needed to remove this table, so I run:

```
DROP TABLE SCHEMA.TABLENAME
```

Later on I want to create a table with the same name as the previous one, but I need it to be empty. I make the same query as earlier, I do:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL HADOOP TABLE SCHEMA.TABLENAME (
  ID BIGINT NOT NULL,
  CODE INTEGER,
  "VALUE" DOUBLE
STORED AS ORC
TBLPROPERTIES ('bigsql.table.io.doAs'='false',
  'bucketing_version'='2',
  'orc.compress'='ZLIB',
  'orc.create.index'='true')
```

But when I create table this way, it has 70.000.000 records inside it again, although I didn't run any job to populate it.
This is why I have two questions:

1. When I drop and create table with old name, then is it recovering records from the old table?
2. How can I drop (or truncate) table in bigsql/hive so that I have an empty table with the old name.

I am using bigsql and hive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dropping an external table doesn't remove the stored data, only the metadata from the Hive Metastore.

Refer [Managed vs External Tables](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Managed+vs.+External+Tables)

Key points...

> - Use external tables when files are already present or in remote locations
> - files should remain even if the table is dropped

Create a managed table (remove `EXTERNAL` from your query), if you want to be able to DROP and/or TRUNCATE.

Or have your Jenkins job run `hadoop fs -rm -skipTrash` before the import.